# How to access constants none static way

Tags: php

if a constant is defined in class like this:

```
class Example
{

   const MIN_VALUE = 0.0;      // RIGHT - Works INSIDE of a class definition.

}
```

it is possible to access the constant like this:

```
Example::MIN_VALUE
```

but if you do this:

```
class Sample {

    protected $example;
    public function __construct(Example $example){
        $this->example = $example;
    }

    public function dummyAccessToExampleConstant(){

        //doesn't work -> syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)
        if($this->example::MIN_VALUE === 0.0){

        }

        //this works
        $tmpExample = $this->example;
        if($tmpExample::MIN_VALUE === 1){

        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain me the reason of this behaviour ?

Is there a good reason or is it just a language construct that prevents the access with "::"

Is there a way how to access a constant with "$this"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those unfortunate shortcomings of PHP's parser. This will work:

```
$example = $this->example;
$min = $example::MIN_VALUE;
```

This won't:

```
$min = $this->example::MIN_VALUE;
```

Edit:

This issue is documented in PHP bug #63789: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63789

It has been fixed, but you will have to wait until PHP's next major release (7).

Comment: You have repeated my example code with other variable names ;-)

Comment: That was intentional. PHP won't let you us the const referencing `::` operator after the property accessor `->`. You have to assign the property to a variable first, then access the const on that variable.

Comment: ok thanks. do you know some official php internals why this isn't implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a class constant. There is no need (and indeed no means) whatsoever to access it in an instance-based way.

You should just access it as `Example::MIN_VALUE` to eliminate any confusion.

PHP > 5.3 allows access via an instance as you have shown (i.e. `$class_instance::CLASS_CONSTANT`) but this is still not to be confused with a property of that instance which can be accessed via `->` (if public of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there a way how to access a constant with "$this"
```

You don't need to access a constant with `$this`, because `$this` refers to the `current instanciated object of a class`. constants can be accessed without instantiating an object.

```
Is there a good reason or is it just a language construct ...
```

A constant, as it's name implies, it's a `constant value`, meaning the value of that variable won't change during execution, that's why you don't need to instantiate an object to access its value.

Hope it's clear !

Comment: No for me this is not clear ;-) I work a lot with dependency injected Objects and sometimes i need to access the constants from there so it breaks my design if i have to access the constants through the static method. From point of view there is a lack in language design but i try to understand why the php designer has decided like they did. Thanks for your answer.